# can not select item when the checkboxlist has only one row and many colums

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, checkboxlist

[image: can not select item when the checkboxlist has only one row]
[image: can select item when the checkboxlist has scrollbar or more than one row]

in c# winform application,i can not select the checkbox when the checkboxlist has only one row,if i use drag the checkboxlist has more than one row or has one row with scrollbar, then i can select the checkbox.

is there any bug in checkboxlist？

Comment: checkboxlist? or DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn?

Comment: checkboxlist. the winform control CheckBoxList not DataGridviewCheckboxColumn

Comment: i have a suggestion, try to use the `DataGridView` it is easy to manage than `CheckBoxList`